Отсутствует звук файла, считываемого при помощи библиотеки NAudio (C#)
Я изучаю библиотеку Naudio. Когда я считываю файл и запускаю его для проигрывания, звук не выводится. Объясните пожалуйста, что я упускаю. Если на подобный вопрос уже отвечали на StackOwerflow, скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на него (я подобного вопроса здесь не нашёл).
Вот код программы:
var file = $"path\\to\\file";
var audioFileReader = new WaveFileReader(file);
var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
waveOut.Init(audioFileReader);
waveOut.Volume = 1.0f;
waveOut.Play()


Убери ненужные табы

Вангую: Console.ReadLine(); в конец. Также, все 2 класса являются IDisposable, не забывайте их закрывать.

Я вам все нужное уже сказал. Если у вас консольное приложение, то код выше не будет ничего ожидать, у вас просто закроется окно и все, без единого "писка". Если будете в конце ждать, любым способом, тогда ваш код будет успешно проигрывать выбранный файл. Так что, повторю "Console.ReadLine(); в конец."

Консоль у меня итак автоматически не закрывается. Особенно с учётом того, что я использую окно, созданное при помощи OpenTK. Ну, кстати, если считать файл вне потока окна OpenTK, то появляется исключение: NAudio.MmException: BadDeviceId calling waveOutOpen.

И где это все в вопросе? Нам от куда знать, что вы там делаете и как? Вот прям скопировал ваш код, вставил в студию, поставил ожидание в конце, запустил, получил такое, как видите, все работает. Так может стоит сразу говорить о спецификациях вашего проекта?...

Если запускать чисто этот блок кода, то он рабочий, а исключение которое я получаю, говорит о том, что у меня проблемы с устройством вывода (что в корне не так).

Вы сейчас это серьезно? Я вас прошу в вопрос всю актуальную информацию добавить, а вы мне сейчас говорите вообще, что ВЕСЬ ваш вопрос бесполезен, ибо в нем есть конкретный код и описание, в котором сказано "запускаю его для проигрывания при помощи кода: ... звук не выводится", то есть, код в вопросе не рабочий. А потом в комментариях пишете "Если запускать чисто этот блок кода, то он рабочий". На наше место встаньте, забудьте всю информацию, которой владеете, ну и попробуйте дать ответ на ваш "рабочий код".  Короче, голосую за закрытие, уж извините.

Добавил весь нужный код.

Для того, чтобы воспроизвести аудио, должно быть правильно указано устройство, через которое будет выводиться звук. Для этого нужно в методе DeviceNumber экземпляра класса WaveOutEvent вручную указать целочисленное значение, например -1 - по умолчанию, 0 - первое устройство вывода, ибо в моём случае значение изначально не было задано или задано некорректно для моего устройства. Подробнее можно почитать тут.
